# Set none if numpy array index does not exist

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I have a function within a Python (2.7) class that should retrieve the values of the 'cells' around it in a 2 dimensional numpy array.  If the index is out of range, I would the value should be set as None.

I'm struggling to find a way to do this without writing 8 try/catch statements, or without using multiple if x else None statements as is in my code below.  While they would both work, they don't seem very well structured, and I'm thinking there must be a simpler way to do this - I'm probably caught thinking about this in entirely the wrong way. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# This will return a dictionary with the values of the surrounding points
def get_next_values(self, column, row):
    if not (column < self.COLUMNS and row < self.ROWS):
        print "Invalid row/column."
        return False

    nextHorizIsIndex = True if column < self.COLUMNS - 2 else False
    nextVertIsIndex = True if row < self.ROWS - 2 else False

    n = self.board[column, row-1] if column > 0 else None
    ne = self.board[column+1, row-1] if nextHorizIsIndex else None
    e = self.board[column+1, row] if nextHorizIsIndex else None
    se = self.board[column+1, row+1] if nextHorizIsIndex and nextVertIsIndex else None
    s = self.board[column, row+1] if nextVertIsIndex else None
    sw = self.board[column-1, row+1] if nextVertIsIndex else None
    w = self.board[column-1, row] if row > 0 else None
    nw = self.board[column-1, row-1] if 0 not in [row, column] else None

    # debug
    print n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw
```

Comment: Watch out for the negative index wrap-around ... !

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a standard trick: Create your board with an edge padded with the value None. Then you can access any inner 3x3 square and fill in the appropriate values with

```
nw, n, ne, w, _, e, sw, s, se = (self.board[column-1:column+2, row-1:row+2]).ravel()
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np

board = np.empty((10,10), dtype = 'object')
board[:,:] = None
board[1:9, 1:9] = np.arange(64).reshape(8,8)
print(board)
# [[None None None None None None None None None None]
#  [None 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 None]
#  [None 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 None]
#  [None 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 None]
#  [None 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 None]
#  [None 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 None]
#  [None 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 None]
#  [None 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 None]
#  [None 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 None]
#  [None None None None None None None None None None]]

column = 1
row = 1
nw, n, ne, w, _, e, sw, s, se = (board[column-1:column+2, row-1:row+2]).ravel()
print(nw, n, ne, w, _, e, sw, s, se)
# (None, None, None, None, 0, 1, None, 8, 9)
```

Note that

- when you define the board this way, the first non-None index is now 1, not 0.
- I think it is more typical to think of the first index as the row,
  and the second index as the column, because when you `print(board)`
  that is the way the values are formatted. So perhaps you want `board[row-1:row+2, column-1:column+2]` instead. Of course, you could define your own `print_board` function, and then be free to use whatever convention you like.

Comment: A good trick, but they may have trouble to use `None` in an array with numeric dtype.  May have to use dtype `object`, which isn't very "numpythonic", or use `nan` instead of `None`.

Comment: True, `nan` might be a better choice if the dtype is float.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful - I wasn't aware of the `board[:,:] = None` syntax either.  My dtype is int, so I'll give it a try padded with `nan`.

Comment: `nan` is compatible with `float` dtypes, but not `int`. You'll need to choose an integer value for `int`. Would a negative number like `-1` be okay?